# Transfer RAID drives from one NAS to another?

Tags: raid, nas, raid-5

My [Patriot Javelin S4 NAS](http://www.patriotmemory.com/product/detail.jsp?prodline=6&catid=44&prodgroupid=160&id=1068&type=25) is pretty slow. I’m thinking about getting a new one, but I have about 7TB of data spread out across four 3TB drives in RAID 5 format. I don’t want to have to buy more hard disks and let it transfer for multiple days. If I just plop the drives into a new NAS, will it understand the RAID format of the other Patriot Javelin S4 NAS? Is it standardized?

Answer (score 2):

#### Shorter answer.

In short, no; you can’t just pop the drives out of one RAID enclosure and pop them in another RAID enclosure and expect it to just work.

RAID array setups are not really standardized and the way each manufacturer—and even different RAID array models from the same manufacturer—deals with RAID metadata varies greatly. If that metadata cannot be read or is in an unexpected format, the new RAID device will simply see those old RAID drives as blank drives that need to be “wiped” before use.

#### Longer answer.

As explained in detail in this answer here on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/324923/100013), if the RAID systems are from different manufacturers the chances of simply reinstalling the drives from one RAID setup to another won’t work.

You could *potentially* do drive a transplant like this when using a RAID setup from the same manufacturer, but that is still not really guaranteed because one manufacturer’s RAID model could use a different RAID subsystem than another model.

That said, such transplants might have more success in higher-end enterprise-level RAID setups but there is still that “Might, maybe, who knows?” factor that could only be confirmed by the manufacturer themselves.